# Llamar formulario de registro de Laravel 5.8 con sesion iniciada

Tags: php, laravel, login

tengo una necesidad simple al utilizar el auth de laravel 5.8 lo cual es que quiero que un usuario pueda crear otros usuarios, pero el formulario de registro del auth al estar con un login activo no me deja acceder, como puedo cambiar eso?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer muchas modificaciones al controller de auth, lo cual te generaría mas problemas, te recomiendo hagas otro formulario.

Comment: supongo que con un controlador diferente

Comment: Si, debe ser un controller diferente que facilmente puedes personalizar